# Convenience initialiser for UIViewController subclass with instance from nib?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to initialise a subclass of `UIViewController` called `TestController`. I have this swift class:

```
class TestController : UIViewController {

    let testString : String
    @IBOutlet weak var test: UITextField!

    required init(withString string: String) {

        self.testString = string
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

}

I also have a nib file called `TestController`, 
[image]

inside it is an instance of `UIViewController`. The file's owner is none (NSObject in grey) and the class of the UIViewController instance in designer is set in the identity inspector to TestController. There is a `UITextField` instance as outlet.

[image]

The problem is the controller is not initialised from the nib (I think), and the textField outlet is nil.

My goal is to allow initialization of controller's instance from nib programmatically, via the custom initialiser. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems: First, your nib (or xib) is not created properly (you shouldn't see `TestController` in interface builder). The easiest way to fix this is to recreate it: New File->Cocoa Touch Class->Create Subclass of `UIViewController`, and don't forget to check **`Also Create a XIB file`**

The second problem is that you're not specifying what nib you want to load. You should specify it in `nibName` parameter of the initializer:

```
super.init(nibName: "NewlyCreatedXib", bundle: nil)
```

When you fix both issues, I believe your code will work properly.